# Passing access_token to FB.login() using JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

So just a quick run down of what I'm working on. I've developed an OAuth library using Google and Facebook to integrate into our company software. Our stack consist of the latest version of Lucee (Coldfusion), so a lot of the authentication was done so manually following their documentation. Although I do use each SDK so that I only have to worry about authenticating the returned tokens server side.

However in regards to Facebook, when a user is already logged in to FB elsewhere, they are already in an `authorize` state when the SDK gets initialized on page load. Whenever I choose to 'Continue With Facebook', edit permissions and deny email permission, I then return back to the user stating as to why we need their email, and provide a button to restart the login flow re-requesting email permission, or just stopping all together.

Though when I choose to add email permission, using `auth_type: 'rerequest'` I get the following error.

```
You are overriding current access token, that means some other app is expecting different access token and you will probably break things. Please consider passing access_token directly to API parameters instead of overriding the global settings.
```

I understand what the error is stating, and why, but I can not figure out how to resolve the issue? From all of the research I've found, everywhere states to pass the access token to the API but all the examples are doing so using a URL endpoint using `href` rather than the SDK login function. Is this something that can be done via their SDK?

Here's what my `FB.login()` function looks like:

```
if( FB.getAccessToken() ) {

    var authType = 'rerequest';

} else {

    var authType = 'reauthorize';
}

FB.login(function(response) {

    // Check to see if user logged in to grant us permission
    if(response.authResponse && response.authResponse.grantedScopes) {

        let isConnected = response.status === 'connected';
        let grantedScopes = response.authResponse.grantedScopes.search('email') !== -1;

        // Need user permission to access email
        if(isConnected && grantedScopes) {

            FacebookAuth.updateSigninStatus();

        } else {

            // Re-ask for email permission
            alertUserError(false, 'Facebook');
        }
    }
}, {
    auth_type: authType,
    scope: 'email',
    return_scopes: true,
    access_token: FB.getAccessToken() // Trying to pass current access_token here, but FB.login() generates new token
});
```

Comment: What’s supposed to be the purpose of passing `access_token: FB.getAccessToken()` in the parameters of the FB.login call?

Comment: @04FS When you are logged into FB, either through FB, or another app, you have an access token. The token is used to represent you, and can be used elsewhere with other applications like a game on a phone, etc. The issue I'm facing when they deny their email, then allow email permission, I need to pass the existing `access_token` to re-request email permissions for my app. Although `access_token: FB.getAccessToken()` does not pass the current access token, and the login function generates a new token, deauthorizing other applications using that use the previous `access_token`.

Comment: You don’t need to explain to me what the purpose of an access token is in general … I asked you what specifically you thought you would achieve by trying to pass `access_token: FB.getAccessToken()` as parameter to `FB.login` _“I need to pass the existing access_token to re-request email permissions for my app”_ - says who?

Comment: That is what the error is saying that Facebook is generating...

Comment: By passing the current access token, I wont be affecting the user if they happen to be using another application that uses their access token.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about here. What other application?

Comment: Another application specifically is irrelevant. I just need to know how to pass the current access_token to the login function, if that is possible, rather than having the FB SDK generate a new token as it currently does.

Comment: No, that is not possible. You can explicitly pass the existing token you have with any `FB.api` calls, but if you want to perform a fresh login, then you will have to deal with the token that gets you. But I don’t see how this would affect any other applications? If you have the JS SDK embedded there as well, it should automatically take care of refreshing tokens in the background when necessary.

Comment: @04FS I appreciate your input on this, and what i've decided to do after reviewing my auth flow as a whole, and the FB docs, was to encrypt the generated access token and store in the database. I can use that record to then validate the user server side rather than making the SDK do so on every page load, in turn generating a new token like what I was experiencing. Sorry it was kinda confusing, but your input helped me rethink how I originally developed the auth flow as a whole, and go about it more efficiently. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took another look at the Facebook Documentation and decided to go the route of storing the access token once is created to verify the user server side. Rather than using the Facebook SDK to do so, which doesn't repeat the login process, creating a new access token, and generating that error.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#token